# Next Gen Gallery Filter By Tag On Galleries

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have NextGen Gallery version 3.1.5 and NextGen Pro version 2.6.8.

I am trying to put a gallery on a page, and have filter buttons above the gallery so that users can filter the images by tag.

Does anybody know of something I'm missing, or have a bit of custom code that can make this work?

I tried using the NextGen Gallery PowerTags plugin, but that broke my site (made it go to a 500 error). I think that plugin doesn't work anymore because of how big this last update by NextGen Gallery was.

Answer (score 0):

Check out justified image grid. Its a plugin to display different gallery sources including nextgen. You can have two levels of filtering.